Inherit from the generic class CompletableFuture
I wish to write async/await code which is JS-friendly, however, my class inheritance doesn't seem to work:
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

class Main {
    public static class Promise<T> extends CompletableFuture<T>{}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        // This works:
        CompletableFuture<String> p1 = Promise.supplyAsync(()->{
            return "foobar";
        });
        // This doesn't, but i need this:
        Promise<String> p2 = Promise.supplyAsync(()->{
            return "foobar";
        });
    }
}

The tricky part is I need to return as Promise<T> not CompletableFuture<T>, making a JS-friendly util.
Error:
ERROR!
/tmp/kpS1aJoUkj/Main.java:13: error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that CompletableFuture<U> conforms to Promise<String>
        Promise<String> p2 = Promise.supplyAsync(()->{
                                                ^
  where U is a type-variable:
    U extends Object declared in method <U>supplyAsync(Supplier<U>)
1 error

If a cast added to the right side of p2, the error is:
ERROR!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture cannot be cast to class Main$Promise (java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Main$Promise is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Tested on https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/

How does changing the class’s name from CompletableFuture to Promise make it more “JS-friendly”?

i make the util with util.async(lambda) and util.await(Promise) too

And how does writing util.async(lambda) instead of CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(lambda) or util.await(Promise) instead of future.join() make the code “more JS-friendly”?

it's just the words

Then, explain how the words help anyone. JS doesn’t care how you name things in a Java program. So, renaming things doesn’t make anything “JS friendly”.

coz my team doing both js and java

Since these are two completely different languages, with different behavior, your team will definitely achieve better results when the programmers can immediately recognize which language’s source code they are looking at. Since every existing API will continue returning futures rather than instances of your promise class, your team mates will have to deal with them anyway. If you really think, you need this, you could write var promise = util.async(…); … util.await(promise); and no one needs to know that the type of promise is CompletableFuture, actually. Then, you don’t need a subclass

The error you get is because supplyAsync() returns a CompletableFuture and you are trying to assign it to a Promise. The assignment correctly fails to compile because a CompletableFuture is not a Promise.
You can work around this by writing your Promise class to be constructible from a CompletableFuture - perhaps by holding the CompletableFuture in a private field and delegating its methods to it.
Then you can override your Promise.supplyAsync to return a Promise which contains the CompletableFuture returned by its super class.

tks 4 your suggestion

I found a work-around, maybe not 100% complete in all cases.
// Make a new supplyAsync to return Promise
CompletableFuture<R> Fut  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Con);
Promise<R>           Prom = new Promise<R>();

Fut.whenComplete((Result,Ex)->{
    if (Ex == null)
        Prom.complete(Result);
    else 
        Prom.completeExceptionally(Ex);
});
return Prom;


what is the down-vote even for? this world can't be happy with these people
